# Input pin stm32g0 always remains low

Tags: stm32, keil, stm32cubeide

I am learning the stm32 using a stm32g070cbt6 micro controller with custom PCB. When I add an external pull-up to the pa4 pin and use it as an input pin. Nevertheless, when I read the pin, the output is low always, even though on the hardware pin is high(3.3v).
Yet I couldn't figure out why it happened. Please assist in finding this problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include "main.h"

void SystemClock_Config(void);

    uint16_t count =0;

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

    RCC->IOPENR |= (1<<0);
    
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~((1<<8) | (1<<9));
    
  while (1)
  {
        if (!(GPIOA->IDR &(1<<4)))  // if the pin is low count should increament
        {
            count++;            
        }
  }
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};


  HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIDiv = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = RCC_PLLM_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 9;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV3;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In your code you're configuring PA8 & PA9, but then you try to read from PA4. How do you know that PA4 is correctly configured?

Comment: Have you enabled the clock to the GPIOA port module in the RCC? I don't see anything in your code which does that.

Comment: @brhans Bits 8 and 9 of MODER are the two bits to select mode for pin 4. Clearing them makes intializes it as input. And setting Bit 0 of IOPENR will the clock enable for GPIO port A. The posted source code is the exact reason why we all love magical mystery values in code (no really, they are useless without deciphering with a reference manual). Maybe the problem is not in code but in hardware.

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the response.But I also checked the hardware side.Always pull up on the pin.
However the value in the IDR register is still low.Could you suggest something I should try?